# Wordpress removing thead tag

Tags: html, wordpress

Does anyone know a fix for wordpress removing the thead table tag when switching from text to visual editors?

I have a basic table

```
<table>
 <thead>
    <th colspan="2">Prizes</th>
 </thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td>1st-5th</td>
    <td>$50 ticket</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>6th-10th</td>
    <td>$31.50 ticket</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>11th-20th</td>
    <td>$10 ticket</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

When i preview this it's working fine. I switch from text to visual and it does the following to the head area

```
<p>Prizes</p>
<table>
<thead></thead>
```

So it removes the TH tag completely and puts the text inside that outside the table and into P tags.

I did have issues like this with P tags and some other tags but after installing TinyMCE Advanced it fixed the issue.

This new issue has only appeared since the last update ( I think ).
WordPress 4.7.5 is current version.